# Odoo 15 how to limit invoicing viewing by created user?

Tags: python, odoo

I created a record rule, I want only the users who created the invoice to be able to view it. I created the record rule, and applied it to the correct module.

```
['|', ('create_uid', '=', user.id), ('invoice_user_id', '=', user.id)]
```

But I get this error

I have double-checked and I am user 2, not sure why I wouldn't be able to view ?

```
    File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 672, in parse
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %s.%s in leaf %s" % (model._name, path[0], str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field account.account.invoice_user_id in leaf ('invoice_user_id', '=', 2)

The above server error caused the following client error:
null
```

Comment: Cause of the error: the field invoice_user_id does not exist in the model account.account